# How to place a different value within a GridView, if the source is a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, datatable

First of all, I've got a DataTable which stores data in a number of fields. One of these fields stores a value, which can either be '1', '0' or '-1'.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to fill a GridView with all the data contained in this DataTable, except for the previously mentioned field. Instead of this field, I would like to display a column which shows a different icon depending on the value (either 0, 1 or -1).

In other words, if a row contains a value of '0' in this field within the DataTable, I would like a red circle icon to appear in the equivalent cell within the GridView.

Could anyone kindly explain how this may be accomplished? Below is some code which may help to explain the situation further.

The GridView is filled with the data contained in the DataTable.

```
source = new DataSource();
TableGridView.DataSource = source.FillTable();
TableGridView.DataBind();
```

What should be done after this?

**EDIT: Solution added as a comment below**

Comment: Solved: I created the TemplateField in ASP.NET code, and the other fields programmatically in the .cs class. Next, I added a chunk of code which switches round the order of the columns. Hope someone finds this helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I created the TemplateField in ASP.NET code, and the other fields programmatically in the .cs class. Next, I added a chunk of code which switches round the order of the columns. Hope someone finds this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are different approaches:

1) you could add a field to your DataTable for the image and fill it with the url of the image that corresponds to the value. Add an image to the GridView and set it's ImageUrl to that field.

2) Add a template field to your GridView and add the 3 images. In the Visible property of the each image you set something like `<% (int)Eval("MyNumericValue") == x %>` (x being 0, 1 or -1) . That way only 1 image is shown, the others hidden (not rendered even).

**from the hip:**

```
<TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:image runat="server" imageurl="~/images/0.png" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("MyNumericValue") == 0 %>' />                
         <asp:image runat="server" imageurl="~/images/1.png" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("MyNumericValue") == 1 %>' />
         <asp:image runat="server" imageurl="~/images/-1.png" Visible='<%# (int)Eval("MyNumericValue") == -1 %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
```

Comment: Jeroen, do you have any idea how to apply this code to an existing column which was created in the back C# code?

Comment: Maybe if you post code on how you create them. There are different ways to do that.

Comment: I dont think it's going to work like that. I think you're making it more complicated than it has to be. Maybe if you post any working code i can help you but this looks like you're just fiddling around.

Comment: I've got it working now. Thanks for the assistance. For anyone with a similar problem, I've added a comment below my question.